# How do I run a java program on a server with Spark?

Tags: java, web-applications, twilio, spark-java

I'm trying to automate a call so that when a user calls a Twilio number, the code will generate XML and send it as an HTTP response to the caller. The example on their webpage goes:

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@WebServlet("/voice")
public class IncomingCallServlet extends HttpServlet {
  // Handle HTTP POST to /voice
  protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
      throws ServletException, IOException {
    // Create a TwiML builder object
    VoiceResponse twiml = new VoiceResponse.Builder()
        .say(new Say.Builder("Hello world!")
              .voice(Say.Voice.ALICE)
              .build())
        .build();

    // Render TwiML as XML
    response.setContentType("text/xml");

    try {
      response.getWriter().print(twiml.toXml());
    } catch (TwiMLException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }



  }
}
```

But how do I get this to run since there's no main method? I'm using spark to run it on a local port then creating a webhook to the application using ngrok. It works if I have a main, but the example here doesn't give any.

Any suggestion on how I'd get this code to run and generate the XML.

Answer (score 2):

Funny thing is, I don't see any reference to Spark in your code, and it could run on any Java Web container, provided that you declare the servlet in a well formed `web.xml`. If I understand your question and code extract correctly, you seem to be willing to rely upon the Jetty server embedded into Spark to load this servlet.

If you want to leverage Spark and avoid the hassle of explicitly declaring your servlet, you could write something like this (assuming you're running Java 8):

```
import com.twilio.twiml.Say;
import com.twilio.twiml.VoiceResponse;

import static spark.Spark.*

public class IncomingCall {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    // You might want to pass the listen port
    // e.g as CLI argument or system property
    port(4567);
    post("/voice", (request, response) -> {
      // Create a TwiML builder object
      VoiceResponse twiml = new VoiceResponse.Builder()
        .say(new Say.Builder("Hello world!")
          .voice(Say.Voice.ALICE)
          .build())
        .build();

      // Render TwiML as XML
      response.type("text/xml");
      try {
          return twiml.toXml();
      } catch (TwiMLException e) {
          // This will result in a HTTP 500
          throw new RuntimeException(e);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Mithfindel, this is a much better way than manually configuring the web.xml. However, the doPost() method takes HTTP req/rep as args. How would I get those without manually instantiating and overriding the necessary methods?

Comment: See SparkJava's request documentation http://sparkjava.com/documentation#request - actually, Spark provides wrappers for the "native" HTTPServlet(Request|Response) objects from Java EE API.

Comment: Also note that ``Spark.post`` method's second argument is a lambda which takes the place of the ``doPost`` method from Twilio's example.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to implement SparkApplication interface, declare a filter in your web.xml and run it in another web server according to the [documentation](http://sparkjava.com/documentation#other-web-server).